# How to fix encoding of video to AV1 so that video scrolling during playback is more smooth?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding

I have encoded the video using AV1 codec (mainly based on [this](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AV1) and [that](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/HighQualityAudio) wiki articles). The resulting video is played OK with [Media Player Classic](https://github.com/mpc-hc) and [Media Player Classic - BE](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mpcbe/), however it is not possible to smoothly scroll/navigate the video (the scroller jumps at certain positions, like 0:06, 1:37). How to fix that so that navigation is more pleasant?

```
D:\> ffmpeg.exe -i 20230421_202618.mp4 -y -nostdin -c:a libopus -b:a 64k -frame_duration 60 -c:v libaom-av1 -crf 28 -b:v 0 -cpu-used 0 20230421_202618_out.av1.mkv
ffmpeg version 2023-04-12-git-1179bb703e-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
...
```

When the same video is encoded to H264, the navigation is much more pleasant (my feeling that key frames are at every 5-10 seconds). Shouldn't it be the same for AV1?

Download links: [AV1 (19MB)](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/yy2cedcnjgv94njejm3m3/20230421_202618_out.av1.mkv), [H264 (46MB)](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/vx2d9jgl6svd2a6txdr86/20230421_202618_out.x264.mkv).

Comment: Similar post [Encoding for smooth forward and backward video playback](https://superuser.com/questions/1139808/encoding-for-smooth-forward-and-backward-video-playback).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When the same video is encoded to H264, the navigation is much more pleasant (my feeling that key frames are at every 5-10 seconds). Shouldn't it be the same for AV1?

As is clearly stated on the FFmpeg wiki page you yourself linked, libaom's default maximum key frame interval is 9999 frames. So no, the key frame interval is not the same as other encoders. You need to set it yourself with the `-g` switch.

Comment: Thanks, I have overlooked that. Just relied that the codec will insert key frames on some reasonable intervals...